# [odoo10]How to save the record while odoo warning is happend?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

In my custom module I added the

```py
application_no = fields.Char(string="Application Number")
```

```py
_sql_constraints = [
 ('application_no_unique',
 'UNIQUE(application_no)',
 "Application Number already exist.Please specify another number or make sure the application number is correct"),
```

]

and I use **sql constraint** to shows warning.

It works correctly, When we entered duplicate application number it shows the warning and access to saving the record is prevented

*Question*

---

How to save the record while warning happens??

*note*

---

I think SQL constraint is not suited for this.
is any other method for this functionality?

Comment: You can use python constraint. It will allow you to write your own logic. Keep note: Return "False" means not allow to save and "True" means allow to save. This will help you https://odedrabhavesh.blogspot.in/2014/12/how-to-create-constraints-in-openerp.html

Comment: You need to save the value even if it is a duplicate ?

Comment: @ WalR:yes, I need to save the value it is duplicate and also shows warning

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it might help you to use an onchange method :

```py
@api.onchange('your_field')
def your_onchange(self):
    count=self.search_count([('your_field','=',self.your_field)])
    return {
        'warning': {'title': _('Warning'), 'message': _('Warning message'),},
         }
```

This will show you the message and you can save without problems. I hope this help you.

Comment: You don't need `@api.multi`.In previous sample self corresponds to the record currently edited on the form. taken from  http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.io/en/latest/decorator.html#api-onchange.

Comment: You are Welcome